# Communication with Keycloak Protected Web App from VS Code Extension

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect, vscode-extensions, keycloak-rest-api

I'm working on a VS Code Extension that needs to regularly send requests to the API of a web app. The web app is protected by an Keycloak Server. My goal is to establish communication without having to log in again with each request. The following picture shows my desired communication process:

[image]

My initial attempt involved using the "[Authorization Code Flow with Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE)](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce)". However, I suspect this may not work as the API and the app might need to be associated. I send a request to Keycloak with a Redirect URL representing the URL of the client in VS Code. If a token is obtained, would it also be valid for the web app?

I would like to know if anyone has experience with a similar integration or if there are alternative approaches to achieve this.

If any crucial information is missing from my description, I apologize in advance and would be happy to provide additional details as needed.

Thank you in advance!